# Consolidate multiple table in single sheet with similar headers using power query or python

Tags: python, excel, powerbi, powerquery

In the excel sheet, I have multiple tables with a similar header. I need help in consolidating all the tables in a single one. My table structure is looking like as below.

Table 1:

| project1 | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| plan | 100 | 200 | 300 |
| forecast | 20 | 40 | 30 |

Table 2:

| project2 | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| plan | 400 | 500 | 600 |
| forecast | 40 | 50 | 60 |

output table:

| projects | Actions | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| project1 | plan | 100 | 200 | 300 |
| project1 | forecast | 10 | 20 | 30 |
| project2 | plan | 400 | 500 | 600 |
| project2 | forecast | 40 | 50 | 60 |

I need to automate this either using python or power query so that I can use it in PowerBI for visualization

Kindly assist me with the correct approach and necessary steps.

Table real structure:
input -  https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4JLf.jpg
output-  https://i.stack.imgur.com/svZxP.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `projects` table to each table in Power Query. The first table would contain `project1`, the second would contain `project2` in the new column. Next create a union of 2 tables (it's called combine in Power Query).

This is for the online version of Power Query, but you'll find (almost) the same for desktop:

[image]

Then to combine the 2 tables:

[image]

You can then fiddle in the advanced editor and do this dynamically for any number of Excel files in a folder, but that's out of scope of a simple question.

Comment: All the tables are on the same table. Please see the real structure of the table from below links:
 input - https://imgur.com/OuUpimS
output- https://imgur.com/esb30xv

Comment: Can you rephrase? I don't really understand your comment.

Comment: Sorry for the above comment... All the tables are in same worksheet. There are n number of tables, it is not fixed. I need to combine all the tables into one table.

Table real structure: input - https://imgur.com/OuUpimS
output- https://imgur.com/esb30xv

Answer (score 0):

Using powerquery

Highlight each table and load into powerquery using

Data .. From Table/Range ... [x] my table has headers

To get the column header added as a repeating row, Add column .. custom column .. with name **projects** and formula

```
= Table.DemoteHeaders(#"Changed Type"){0}[Column1]
```

save and close using file ... close and load to .. only create connection..

full code for each table would be similar to this

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"project1", type text}, {"2018", Int64.Type}, {"2019", Int64.Type}, {"2020", Int64.Type}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Table.DemoteHeaders(#"Changed Type"){0}[Column1])
in #"Added Custom"
```

Then just append the data from all the tables.

Data ... Get Data .. Combine Queries ... Append ...  and then add each table

which will produce code similar to

```
let Source = Table.Combine({Table1, Table2, Table3}) in Source
```